# Is there a way to define the relative position of items in print composer?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, layouts, alignment

Is there any chance to make the items in print composer relative to the margins. Let's say for example the legend. I normally align it to the corner on the right bottom where the legend is 10 px away from the boarders of the map.

If I add a new item to the legend, the legend gets bigger and I have to align it again. To give the legend a relative position independently from the legends size would be very favourable (tell qgis to always align the legend in the corner on the right bottom with a distance of 10 px always). Than I could define one layout and make several maps without readjusting those items all over again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, but it's a good request. Can you please file it over at http://hub.qgis.org?

Comment: ok just did so.