# Connecting layout text boxes to item before it in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, atlas, text

I have an atlas layout in QGIS 3.16 where input data can vary in character length. Therefore I made a override of box height based on text length. The problem I ran into, is that if the text is longer it goes over the next text box. I want to make this text box dependent on min. y position point of box item before. So is there a way to make a relative position of item in layout based on item before?

Normal position:

[image: normal position]

Longer text:

[image]

What I want it to look like.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any relative positioning. Maybe it was implemented already like asked in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108602/is-there-a-way-to-define-the-relative-position-of-items-in-print-composer).

Another approach would be to have only one `Text Label Input` and use `HTML Styling`. You would only need to replace the div content with your input data:

```
[%'<h2>Box1:</h2><div style="border: 1px solid black">Foobar</div>
<br><br>
<h2>Box2:</h2><div style="border: 1px solid black">Foobaz</div>
'%]
```

[image: Render as HTML]

Comment: Thanks... this solves simple problems, but if my next item is not text (for example map), this can not be solved with that solution. I've seen the post you linked. I will ask if any implementations were made.